# How to validate availability of username in database?

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf

How can I validate the entered username in an input text field if it is available according to the database? I am using JSF2.

Comment: what is the "check availability feature" do you mean?

Comment: hi ken, I want to cross verify the given USERNAME in the text box with the Data Base whether username is alloted to anybody or not.

Answer (score 6):

Just implement a [`Validator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/validator/Validator.html) yourself.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class UserNameAvailableValidator implements Validator {

    @EJB
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        String userName = (String) value;

        if (!userService.isUsernameAvailable(userName)) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Username not avaliable"));
        }
    }

}
```

*(please note that it's a `@ManagedBean` instead of `@FacesValidator` because of the need to inject an `@EJB`; if you're not using EJBs, you can make it a `@FacesValidator` instead)*

Use it as follows:

```html
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{register.user.name}" required="true">
    <f:validator binding="#{userNameAvailableValidator}" />
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="username_message" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message id="username_message" for="username" />
```